# Partition warning message in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast v3.2.4.  The server loads up with some mapstore implementations.  When the map store eager loading occurs at startup time, I see this warning message (the heap still appears to have space).  I am not sure what might be causing this warning message. What might be causing this and how best to resolve it?

```
2014-09-12 17:36:00,871 WARN c.h.p.InternalPartitionService [hz._hzInstance_1_test.cached.thread-9] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [test] [3.2.4] Owner of partition is being removed! Possible data loss for partition[95]. PartitionReplicaChangeEvent{partitionId=95, replicaIndex=0, oldAddress=Address[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701, newAddress=null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience of using Hazelcast i advice you to wait some time after your hazelcast instance is initialized. this message often could be seen when you start/stop hz instances while writing data to hazelcast cluster.
For more detailed explanation i need to see your IMap configuraton